# Pipeline Syntax generated script via "Pipeline: SCM Step'' plugin where "Unexpected token <" found in "password: <object of type hudson.util.Secret>"

Tags: jenkins, version-control, jenkins-groovy, password-encryption, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

While I am using password in Pipeline syntax to generate script to checkout CVS repo it's showing `unexpected token <`. Also in script there is `password: <object of type hudson.util.Secret>` which is responsible for the issue.

Here is the generated script by Pipeline Syntax. I've used 'example' instead of real value.

```
checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'CVSSCM', canUseUpdate: true, checkoutCurrentTimestamp: true, cleanOnFailedUpdate: false, disableCvsQuiet: false, forceCleanCopy: true, legacy: false, pruneEmptyDirectories: true, repositories: [[compressionLevel: -1, cvsRoot: ':example:example@8.8.8.8:/cvs', excludedRegions: [[pattern: '']], password: <object of type hudson.util.Secret>, passwordRequired: true, repositoryItems: [[location: [$class: 'BranchRepositoryLocation', branchName: 'example_branch', useHeadIfNotFound: false], modules: [[localName: 'example', remoteName: 'example']]]]]], skipChangeLog: false]
```

Output after running the job
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YixZe.png)

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing here is: the `<object of type hudson.util.Secret>` is a placeholder for an object of type `hudson.util.Secret`. You can find the API docs [here](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/util/Secret.html).

You will probably not need to create a Secret, though. You can just as well get it from Jenkins credentials.

1. configure CVS credentials (probably username and password, I can't remember how CVS authentication worked) in your Jenkins configuration. See [the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) on how to do that.
2. wrap your checkout statement in a `withCredentials` step, which can be created using the pipeline syntax help as well.

I have created a username/password credential in my Jenkins sandbox and it got the ID `338cbf3f-c978-455f-8816-423d3e959ea9`. The `withCredentials` step extracts the secret into an environment variable. In the example we use `CHECKOUT_PASSWORD` and provide it to the `checkout` step by using `env.CHECKOUT_PASSWORD`:

```
node {
  withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '338cbf3f-c978-455f-8816-423d3e959ea9', passwordVariable: 'CHECKOUT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'CHECKOUT_USER')]) {
    checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [$class: 'CVSSCM', canUseUpdate: true, checkoutCurrentTimestamp: false, cleanOnFailedUpdate: false, disableCvsQuiet: false, forceCleanCopy: false, legacy: false, pruneEmptyDirectories: true, repositories: [[compressionLevel: -1, cvsRoot: 'cvs://root', excludedRegions: [[pattern: '']], password: env.CHECKOUT_PASSWORD, passwordRequired: true, repositoryItems: [[location: [$class: 'HeadRepositoryLocation'], modules: [[localName: 'localName', remoteName: 'remoteName']]]]]], skipChangeLog: false]
  }
}
```

As I said, I am not completely sure about how to use CVS anymore. You may just as well get away with replacing the `<object of type hudson.util.Secret>` with `''` and passing `false` as value for the `passwordRequired` parameter.